# Parsing large JSON files

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code for reading a json file into pandas dataframe and parsing the fields, but it is too slow for large files. Is there a way to make the code more efficient?

```
def extract_text(json_train_path):


    with open(json_train_path, 'r') as json_file:


        train = {'example_id':[],
                    'question':[], 
                    'text':[], 
                    'long_answer':[],
                    'long_answer_text':[],
                    'short_answer':[],
                    'short_answer_text':[],
                    'yes_no_answer':[]}

        # extract files
        for line in tqdm(json_file):
                data = json.loads(line)

                example_id = str(data['example_id'])
                question = data['question_text']

                # clean text
                text = data['document_text']
                text = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml").text
                #text = text.lower()

                long_start = data['annotations'][0]['long_answer']['start_token']
                long_end = data['annotations'][0]['long_answer']['end_token']
                long_answer_text = text.split(' ')[long_start:long_end]
                long_answer_text = ' '.join(long_answer_text)

                yes_no_answer = data['annotations'][0]['yes_no_answer']

                if yes_no_answer == 'NONE':
                    yes_no_answer = ''

                if data['annotations'][0]['short_answers']:
                    short_start = data['annotations'][0]['short_answers'][0]['start_token']
                    short_end = data['annotations'][0]['short_answers'][0]['end_token']
                    short_answer = (f'{short_start}:{short_end}')
                    short_answer_text = text.split(' ')[short_start:short_end]
                    short_answer_text = ' '.join(short_answer_text)

                else:                 
                    short_start = ''
                    short_end = ''
                    short_answer_text = ''
                    short_answer = ''

                # construct the DataFrame
                train['example_id'].append(example_id)
                train['question'].append(question)
                train['text'].append(text)
                train['long_answer'].append(f'{long_start}:{long_end}')
                train['long_answer_text'].append(long_answer_text)
                train['short_answer'].append(short_answer)
                train['short_answer_text'].append(short_answer_text)
                train['yes_no_answer'].append(yes_no_answer)


    return train
```

This is an example of a line of json being parsed

```
document_text   long_answer_candidates  question_text   annotations document_url    example_id
0   Email marketing - Wikipedia <H1> Email marketi...   [{'start_token': 14, 'top_level': True, 'end_t...   which is the most common use of opt-in e-mail ...   [{'yes_no_answer': 'NONE', 'long_answer': {'st...   https://en.wikipedia.org//w/index.php?title=Em...   5655493461695504401
```

Comment: The posted sample does not look valid. Post a testable valid fragment that comes to `data = json.loads(line)`

Comment: Also, how large is large? Is your JSON file GBs, TBs?

Comment: @Graipher It is about 5 GB